# Unique Permission for Approvers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, permissions

I need help in order to resolve a problem that I'm having with our SharePoint.
We have a custom list with specific permissions. When performing a task process of one item with SharePoint Designer, we can not obtain specific permissions to approvers of the task process.

We need that the approvers of the items of the custom list only have access to the specific list. However, I am only able to review the task notifications when they have `Approver` permission level for all the site.

Is there a way to limit the approve permission only for the specific list in order to approve the items of the same?

Comment: Go to the respective list setting->Permissions for this list-> break the inheritance->Remove unwanted groups->Add the approver group.

Comment: Also make sure the `Workflow Tasks` list has `Approvers` group added.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to break inheritance on the custom list and then assign or remove permissions as needed.

I think that approvers will access this custom list only through the url directly .